# Does City and Zip in Address Table Violate BCNF

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, bcnf

Let's say you have a the following

```
 ---------------------------
  attribute      constraints
| --------       -----------   
| id             (PK)
| location_name  **
| street         
| zipcode        
| city           

** realistically Unique, but not going to use for future proofing?
```

Would this violate BCNF as zipcode can be used to find the city? Although cities can share zipcodes and vise versa, a city can't be in two separate zipcodes where another city is part of that zipcode?
(zipcode1 --> city1) and (zipcode2 --> city1 and city2)

(note that zipcode and city are not a composite superkey as multiple locations can be associated with the same zipcode and city). Is BCNF suggesting that you should a completely separate table JUST for pairing cities and zipcodes?

States are omitted because this database is for a single state. Although in that case would you have to have 3 tables since a zipcode cannot be in multiple states (edit: apparently there are, but assuming there aren't). Seems too dumb to me true and that wayy too many unions would be needed.

I honestly dont understand much of anything regarding key terms and have just been left confused (if you could answer in layman's terms and/or technically that's highly appreciated). I tried searching for an answer because I figured it would be common, but couldn't find anything. Given my inability to organize and process mathematical logic, i'm starting to wonder if I picked the wrong field to enter..

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? PS Re zip codes, about the only constraint is that a street address & city & state has 1 zip code. But if this is homework we can expect you were told what the constraints are or you are supposed to pick or research reasonable ones with justification--what were you told exactly? Homework or not, when your question is clear, show relevant research. Re location_name, you don't say what that is so we can't help you yet. Re FDs & BCNF, quote definitions & ask re where 1st stuck. Phrasings like "used to find" are not helpful. [ask] [help]

Comment: No.  A city can have more than one zip code and a zip code can cover more than one city (actually jurisdiction).  The only sure thing you can get with a zip code is the state.  Unless your database is concerned with addresses, it's fine to keep the city and zip code in the address table.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Nope, a zip code can cross states.

Comment: It is for a school project, not some random homework question (100% my own use case). but the only Req is that it must all maintain BCNF.  The use case I designed is based on having an organization with multiple locations within the same state (Hawaii so no expansion possible). Contact and location info is stored for it to be easily accessible and to allow the id to be a foreign key in another table. I know that realistically it would just tie into a USPS API, but that's not doable really for a database with zero API/front end application. I didnt include the other info b/c it wasnt relevant.

Comment: First, what is your 1 question?

Comment: If the purpose of BCNF is that a determinate must be a candidate key, does storing a zipcode and city in the same table multiple times for different addresses violate this as a zipcode and city are dependent on one another.

Comment: Please clariy via edits, not comments. But that comment is unclear. Why are you prefixing with an "if"? It has nothing to do with the "does" after. Also "purpose" isn't clear, BCNF is a condition that is either met or not. And it isn't that a determinant must be a CK. "dependent on one another" is not clear. You still haven't acted on all of my 1st comment. Get the definition of FD, research or define zip codes & ask re being stuck the 1st time you can't determine whether an FD holds. Ie follow your textbook & ask re where you are 1st stuck, don't ask us to rewrite it with a bespoke tutorial.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Comment: I know what an FD is... Why would I be asking the question otherwise. no need to be rude.

Comment: Suppose we ignore the title & stop at the first question mark. Then you have given the columns, PK {id}, an unclear "realistically ...", an unclear "zipcode can be used to find the city" & asked "does this violate BCNF?", and the post can stop. Now please clarify, and show research. (3 clauses in the remainder might be relevant to clarifying/solving.) PS I was not rude, your question right now asks us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

What does a five digit zipcode actually determine?  As I understand it, it determines a Post Office.  This is enough to route every piece of mail from wherever it is to a destination post office.  That post office then deliver it locally.

Figuring out what the dependencies are between zip code and state or zip code and city, or zip code and street plus number or apartment number can be the devil's own business.

The area served by a post office is generally part of some community that the Post Office is in,  like a town.  But there are quirks.
The residents of Magalloway, ME are served by the post office in nearby Errol,  NH.  They therefore use zipcode 03579, the same as the residents of downtown Errol.  The letters get forwarded to the Errol post office,  then delivered to them in Maine.  This may seem very strange, but it works out well in terms of driving miles.

[map of 03579](https://www.bing.com/maps?&ty=18&q=03579%2c%20Errol%2c%20New%20Hampshire&satid=id.sid%3a440f2264-bea6-35bb-d28e-4342e2cea3e7&vdpid=5487791303288684545&mb=44.992207%7E-71.440536%7E44.705849%7E-70.969017&ppois=44.84902763366699_-71.20477676391602_03579%2c%20Errol%2c%20New%20Hampshire_%7E&cp=44.849028%7E-71.204777&v=2&sV=1&FORM=MIRE&qpvt=zipcode+03579)